# how to make customized poster with php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, customization

I am working on a web project in which you can make customized poster like they can club multiple images, draw art and write texts.Then user can download this customized poster. I use technologies like php, jQuery, html5.Please suggest me the way to do this.Thanks in advance.

Here is the Link for demo site what i want to achieve :

```
 http://www.postermywall.com/
```

Comment: @SyedQarib:i just want to confirm that is it possible to do it with php and jquery  or html5.

Comment: look for Php ImageMagick ..

Comment: @SyedQarib: thanks i'm working on this but is there any other library or script we can use, or is ther any sample?

Comment: @SyedQarib: thats the first thing i have done brother...:) but thanks anyways.